# Casting to Type from Type Object

Tags: c#, casting, runtime

Consider my code:

```
public class MyClass
{
//...
}

object ob = new MyClass();
Type t = ob.GetType();
```

With this information, I need to cast `ob` to `MyClass` at run-time.
How do I do this?

Comment: Millions of similar questions on SO ;) Why don't you know the type of your objects at compile time?

Comment: To cast `ob` to type `MyClass` just use `(MyClass)ob`. But is this what you're asking?

Comment: Please tell *why* you need to do this.

Comment: @DominicKexel, Why I need this:

Simple, I have a list of class names from which I want to create object of them, one by one.

Answer (score 3):

**[`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)** is what you are looking for.

```
// With ob and t from your example.
var myClassInstance = Convert.ChangeType(ob, t);
```

But as some people suggest, it would be good to know why do you need this in the first place. Chances are there's a smell in your approach to the problem and it can be done easier, without any type kung-fu.

Comment: This I have tried, but `ChangeType` method is gonna return type `Object`, not the type I want

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `MyClass` is known at compile time:

```
object ob = new MyClass();

if (ob.GetType() != typeof(MyClass))
        MyClass convertedObject = (MyClass)ob;
```

Comment: I assume that OP doesn't know at compile time that it's a `MyClass` because he uses `GetType`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter made the edit to check first if ob is a type of MyClass

Comment: Then [@Blachshma's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13930381/284240) is better. But both of you are assuming that the type `MyClass` is known at compile time.